# concatenate two or more uniform meshes in fipy

Tags: python, fipy

is it possible to concatenate two (or more) meshes?
Example:

```
import fipy
meshA = fipy.Grid2D(nx=5, ny=3)
meshB = fipy.Grid2D(nx=5, ny=6)
mesh = fipy.vstack(meshA, meshB)
```

Same goes for 1D, or 2D grids.

Intermediate Question: Is it possible to define an offset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, and you actually have to do the second to do the first:

`mesh = meshA + (meshB + [[0], [3]])`

which displaces meshB upwards by 3 units and then concatenates it to meshA.

This is covered in the docstring for `Mesh.__add__`, but the Sphinx documentation tool unfortunately doesn't include that in the output. We'll need to explicitly put this in the documentation where it can be read.

Note that the resulting mesh is no longer a Grid and so loses some efficiencies. For this simple case, you're obviously better off just setting `ny=9`. For a bit more complicated case, you might want to do:

`mesh = fipy.Grid2D(nx=5, dy=[1,1,1,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5,.5])`

if the reason you're grafting meshes is to change the resolution.

Comment: Thank you very much. The reason I want to use this, is to define two domains with different resolution (in only one dimension). I think the solution with `dy` beeing an array suites me the best.

Comment: BTW: I just tried `mesh = fipy.Grid2D(nx=5, dy=[1]*2+[.5]*4, Lx=3, Ly=1)` and its cell centers do not look right. It seems to ignore the `Lx` and `Ly` input.

Comment: I'd say that `mesh = fipy.Grid2D(nx=5, dy=[1]*2+[.5]*4, Lx=3, Ly=1)` does the "right" thing, but it doesn't do what we document. I'm curious what cell centers you expected, as there's no way to reconcile `dy=[1]*2+[.5]*4` and `Ly=1`.

Comment: Yep... bad thinking on my part. I expected, that instead of defining the length from the sum of cell-widths, it would scale all cells to a total length of `Ly`, while maintainig their relative width ratios.